# How to set a linux box to receive emails using my email address

Tags: linux, email

I am planning to use my enterprise email address ( I am working at a company) as a medium for commands. And I want this to work on a linux box, I need by email to be registered there so that if an email comes it will be registered.

Example:

I will send an email with a subject: **getsummary**

then at a linux box(linux os) received an email with that subject, I want it to execute a perl script I made to send a summary back to the requestor.

Comment: Pls describe what you have already done.

Comment: This is just my Plan. I have a script to reply based on what what arg it will receive or read.

Comment: You should look at existing auto-responder scripts.  It basically needs to connect to your email server, retrieve the messages, parse them, and react accordingly.  Once you get it started, if you get stuck, go to stackoverflow.com as this is a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd split you task into two steps: **getting** emails and **parsing** emails, because second step depends of first one, if you cannot get emails then you have nothing to parse.
First step depends of `MX` records and ways you can access `MX` server. Since you have stated that email is enterprise, I assume that you cannot just change the `MX` records. I drew related flowchart.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your linux box is running X you can use email clients' feature: execute script on receiving emails. In the [claws mail](http://www.claws-mail.org/)  it looks like this:
[image]

If your linux box is not running X you can use fetchmail&procmail.
Here is the description: http://openthought.net/docs/database/MailFilteringHowto